# Python: Linking to a dictionary through a text string

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program module that contains data structures (dictionaries) and  text strings that describe those data structures.  I want to import these (dictionaries and descriptions) into a module that is feeding a GUI interface. One of the displayed lines is the contents contained in the first dictionary with one field that contains all possible values contained in another dictionary.  I'm trying to avoid 'hard-coding' this relationship and would like to pass a link to the second dictionary (containing all possible values) to the string describing the first dictionary.  An abstracted example would be:

```
dict1 = {
    "1":["dog","cat","fish"],
    "2":["alpha","beta","gamma","epsilon"]
         }
string="parameter1,parameter2,dict1"

# Silly example starts here
#
string=string.split(",")
print string[2]["2"]
```

(I'd like to get:  `["alpha","beta","gamma","epsilon"]`

But of course this doesn't work

Does anyone have a clever solution to this problem?

Comment: Awesome.  I'm not worthy, I'm not worthy . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, this kind of dynamic code execution is a bad idea.  it leads to very difficult to read and maintain code.  However, if you must, you can use `globals` for this:

```
globals()[string[2]]["2"]
```

A better solution would be to put `dict1` into a dictionary in the first place:

```
dict1 = ...
namespace = {'dict1': dict1}

string = ...
namespace[string[2]]["2"]
```